# Windows 10, Django 1.8.6, Pycharm 5.0.1 not restarting app

Tags: django, pycharm, windows-10

I have to manually restart the server since I've updated from Django 1.6 to 1.8.6. Anyone have any idea why it's not restarting when changes are done to the code? not even if I change settings.py.

Also I'm using django-sslserver.

Comment: what server do you use? django server? gunicorn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that django-sslserver is not up to date with Django 1.8 changes. So it's broken: [Github Issue](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver/issues/38)